# How to separate values from a params hash in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a form with this

```
check_box_tag "upgrade[#{user.id}]"
```

On next page, If i do

```
params[:upgrade]
```

I get 161 as value, but I would like only the id which is 16.

How can I separate only to get the first value?

When I do debug params[:upgrade] I get:

```
--- !map:ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess 
    "16": "1"
```

Thank you!

Comment: It's weird because when I do it looks nil

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you have to write like this:

```
check_box_tag "upgrade[]", user.id
```

For reference please see this [railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/17-habtm-checkboxes)